What are the security risks in using a simple @if for authentication in blazor server?
Let's say I have a razor page where I use a simple @if(SimpleAuth.IsAdmin) to show it if the user is an admin.
@inject SimpleAuth SimpleAuth

@if (SimpleAuth.IsAdmin) 
{
    <p>protected content</p>
}

I have the SimpleAuth.cs handling the authentication which will set
public bool IsAdmin { get; private set; } = false;

based on some authentication mechanism.
I add the SimpleAuth service like this:
builder.Services.AddScoped<SimpleAuth>();

Provided this is a Blazor server project, can this be bypassed by the client without say having a flaw in the auth mechanism itself?

The short answer is no, the if statement cannot be bypassed directly from the client in a Blazor Server app.
However, you may want to use an AuthorizeView component instead of an if. Combine this with a custom AuthenticationStateProvider. In this way, your implementation will be more standard, scalable and future-proof in case you decide to:

Change the authentication algorithm.
Support multiple authentication roles.
Restrict access to complete .razor components or "pages" to authenticated users or roles.

